# Reasonable expectation of Nvidia 2080 SUPER performance on new monitor

Tags: graphics-card, display, performance

Not super sure what forum this goes on, here seems like the place... I recently, somewhat on impulse, upgraded the graphics card in my desktop from a Nvidia 1060 to a 2080 SUPER, and my trusty 1920x1080 60hz monitor is simply not able to handle it. With games, which I figure are the best way to benchmark run triple-A titles (the only two I really have being Witcher 3 and Assasins Creed: Odyssey), at the highest possible graphical settings, and and it barely ever uses more than 15-20% of the GPU, even Skyrim, as ridiculously unoptimized as it is, running every 3rd party enhancer I can find, at most uses 40%. So I figured, well, guess I need to upgrade. So, I went out and got an LG 34GK950F, an ultrawide 3440x1440 120-144hz beast of a thing, though it runs FreeSync, not G-Sync, which I didn't realise was vendor-specific until after I had it, and is simply disabled, and now I have the opposite problem. I can't get above 70fps in any of these games, and the card is consistently at max usage whilst running them. So my question is, is this expected performance, and have I just bit off more than it could chew, or could there something else I don't know about causing this bottleneck? I just find it hard to take in, because, while it's no Ti, it's the second most powerful gaming-focued card Nvidia has right now, and if it can't run this thing, then what can?

Comment: Pure guess, you're now CPU bottlenecked, not GPU. [I won't even mention you cannot see 120Hz… but that's where those screen makers make their money, by convincing you & other gamers that you can… & your life depends on it. ;)

Comment: In my monitoring, the CPU was just fine, the GPU was constantly maxed out. And, I'm at best a very casual gamer, I've never touched an FPS in my life, so... Yeah, I'm inclined to agree with you on that point... I've found I've noticed, barely, the difference between 60hz and 100, but beyond that, no.

Comment: I suppose the sensation here is similar to guys who like cars buying something that can easily reach 200mph even though the speed limit is never higher than 80.

Comment: Indeed - & though this is not directed at you at all, there is more than a hint of "schoolboy brag"… well, because they can't afford cars that can do 200mph, so they compare fps ;-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just expected performances, even with a 2080 ti running any AAA game (Ultra Quality) at 4k with 120hz will result in 60-100 fps.
You can easily verify this by watching video performances on youtube.
here an example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fj-R8l776yM.

If you want to improve performances you should buy another gpu and try to combine them using nvidia sli.